# Can you resize overflowdirect window in tkinter without flicker when adjusting position and width at the same time?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, winapi, window

I have an `overridredirect` window that I need to resize on mouse drag.

The example is functioning, but when I drag any of: `sw`, `w`, `nw`, `n` and `ne` handles it causes flicker (most noticeable when dragging fast). This is likely due to adjusting position and size simultaneously.

I tried `update_idletasks` to see if that would smooth out the transition but, it didn't.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Box(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.drag_point_x = None
        self.drag_point_y = None
        self.drag_margin = 15
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 200
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 300

        self.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}+{self.x}+{self.y}")
        self.overrideredirect(1)

        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_dragging)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_click)
        self.bind("<Motion>", self.on_motion)

    def on_dragging(self, event):
        mouse_x = self.winfo_pointerx()
        mouse_y = self.winfo_pointery()
        delta_width = self.x - mouse_x
        delta_height = self.y - mouse_y

        if self.drag_point == 'e':
            self.width = mouse_x - self.x
        elif self.drag_point == 'se':
            self.width = mouse_x - self.x
            self.height = mouse_y - self.y
        elif self.drag_point == 's':
            self.height = mouse_y - self.y
        elif self.drag_point == 'sw':
            self.height = mouse_y - self.y
            self.width += delta_width
            self.x = mouse_x
        elif self.drag_point == 'w':
            self.width += delta_width
            self.x = mouse_x
        elif self.drag_point == 'nw':
            self.width += delta_width
            self.height += delta_height
            self.x = mouse_x
            self.y = mouse_y
        elif self.drag_point == 'n':
            self.height += delta_height
            self.y = mouse_y
        elif self.drag_point == 'ne':
            self.width = mouse_x - self.x
            self.height += delta_height
            self.y = mouse_y
        self.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}+{self.x}+{self.y}")

    def on_click(self, event):
        self.drag_point_x = event.x
        self.drag_point_y = event.y

    def on_motion(self, event):
        if event.x < self.drag_margin:
            if event.y < self.drag_margin:
                self.config(cursor="size_nw_se")
                self.drag_point = "nw"
            elif event.y > self.height - self.drag_margin:
                self.config(cursor="size_ne_sw")
                self.drag_point = "sw"
            else:
                self.config(cursor="size_we")
                self.drag_point = "w"
        elif event.x > self.width - self.drag_margin:
            if event.y < self.drag_margin:
                self.config(cursor="size_ne_sw")
                self.drag_point = "ne"
            elif event.y > self.height - self.drag_margin:
                self.config(cursor="size_nw_se")
                self.drag_point = "se"
            else:
                self.config(cursor="size_we")
                self.drag_point = "e"
        elif event.y < self.drag_margin:
            self.config(cursor="size_ns")
            self.drag_point = "n"
        elif event.y > self.height - self.drag_margin:
            self.config(cursor="size_ns")
            self.drag_point = "s"
        else:
            self.config(cursor="")
            self.drag_point = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    box = Box()
    box.mainloop()
```

UPDATE:

Here's code based on OneMadGypsy's solution that adds multiple monitor support:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab
from screeninfo import get_monitors


class Overlay(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, monitor, overlays):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.b_x = 0
        self.b_y = 0
        self.e_x = 0
        self.e_y = 0
        self.drag = False
        self.overlays = overlays
        self.monitor = monitor

        self.configure(cursor='cross')
        self.attributes('-alpha', 0.3)
        self.attributes('-topmost', True)

        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.geometry(f"{self.monitor.width}x{self.monitor.height}+{self.monitor.x}+{self.monitor.y}")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='dark gray')
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.on_drag)
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.on_press)
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.on_release)
        rect = dict(
            outline='#0052d6',
            fill='white',
            tags='snip_rect',
            width=2,
        )
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, **rect)

    def on_press(self, event):
        self.b_x = event.x
        self.b_y = event.y

    def on_drag(self, event):
        self.drag = True
        self.e_x = event.x
        self.e_y = event.y
        self.canvas.coords('snip_rect', self.b_x, self.b_y, self.e_x, self.e_y)

    def on_release(self, event):
        self.destroy()
        for window in self.overlays:
            if window:
                window.destroy()
        self.overlays.clear()

        if not self.drag:
            return

        adjusted_b_x = self.b_x + self.monitor.x
        adjusted_b_y = self.b_y + self.monitor.y
        adjusted_e_x = self.e_x + self.monitor.x
        adjusted_e_y = self.e_y + self.monitor.y

        image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(min(adjusted_b_x, adjusted_e_x),
                                     min(adjusted_b_y, adjusted_e_y),
                                     max(adjusted_b_x, adjusted_e_x),
                                     max(adjusted_b_y, adjusted_e_y)), all_screens=True)
        image.show()



class Snipper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = None
        self.overlays = []

    def snip(self):
        monitors = get_monitors()

        for monitor in monitors:
            overlay = Overlay(monitor, self.overlays)
            self.overlays.append(overlay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    class App(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, **kwargs)
            self.image = None
            self.windows = []
            self.snipper = Snipper()
            tk.Button(self, text='snip', width=50, command=self.snipper.snip).pack()

    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your dimensions sometimes turn out to be negative. `self.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}+{self.x}+{self.y}")` `_tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "-28x317+300+87"`

Comment: I've made this window a couple of times in the last 5 years, and the problem you are having is the same one I always had. It will get worse when you start adding things to the window. My work has been heavily centered around tkinter for a long time. I definitely know what I am doing and I was never able to figure out even a trick to make it stop. One may exist, but I believe you are likely going to end up spinning your wheels to no end. IIRC, the "edge-jumping" doesn't happen on Linux. This is a windows problem.

Comment: I remembered what my work around was. Only allow resizing of the window from the right, bottom and right-bottom. If you think about it, why do you need to be able to resize from any spot, and in any direction? Isn't 3 handles enough? Your cursor can make it clear to the user which edges allow sizing. Really you only need 1 handle. The bottom right corner can size the window on any axis, and is a common grab spot.

Comment: @СергейКох This is a minimal reproducible example. Full code takes that into account.

Comment: @JasonFyle What OS are you using? If it's Unix, try adding the `x11` tag to the question. If it's Windows, try adding the `WinAPI` tag to the question. I can try to convert `c` code that uses `x11`/`winapi` into python code.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy
Thanks for sharing your experience. If someone solves it, it would be great from UX perspective, as this window/box is used to select part of the screen to take a screenshot (the final box will be empty, green, always on top and semitransparent). Now, I'm torn between what you suggest or just accepting the flicker, as it isn't substantial.

Comment: @TheLizzard That sounds promissing. It's Windows, so I added the WinAPI tag.

Comment: Here's what else you can read. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000291/how-to-smooth-ugly-jitter-flicker-jumping-when-resizing-windows-especially-drag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have made it clear what you actually want to do, may I suggest this method. The short explanation is: When "snip" button is pressed, the entire screen is taken over by a semi-transparent `tk.Toplevel` with a `tk.Canvas` child. You drag out a square on the canvas (ie, no window resizing), and release to lock it in. Then click "save" to save the image within the rect you just drew. It doesn't have "after-the-fact" controls for adjustment but, it works very smooth and emulates much of what you explained in the comments. Use this code all you like and in any way you like.

Please note that I wrote this like 5 years ago. I see things I would definitely do differently now, but it's all "code style" related. I don't see any major refactors here.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from os import mkdir, path, getcwd
from time import strftime
from PIL import ImageGrab


class Button(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, text, command, row, column, **kwargs):
        self.default = {**dict(
            foreground       = 'gray60',
            background       = 'gray10',
            activebackground = 'gray60',
            activeforeground = 'gray10',
            font             = 'Helvetica 28 bold',
            padx             = 10,
            pady             = 10,
            border           = 2,
        ), **kwargs}
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master, text=text, command=command, **self.default)
        self.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='nswe')
        
        self.hover = self.default.copy()
        self.hover['background'] = 'steel blue'
        self.hover['foreground'] = 'black'
        
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
        
    def on_enter(self, event):
        if self['state'] != 'disabled':
            self.configure(**self.hover)
        
    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.configure(**self.default)

        
class ScreenSnip(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        #config toplevel
        self.configure(cursor='cross')
        self.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.attributes('-alpha', 0.2)
        
        #init vars
        self.b_x = 0
        self.b_y = 0
        self.e_x = 0
        self.e_y = 0
        self.drag= False
        
        #create and config canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='dark gray')
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.on_drag)
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.on_press)
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.on_release)
        rect = dict(
            outline = '#0052d6',
            fill    = 'white',
            tags    = 'snip_rect',
            width   = 2,
        )
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, **rect)

    def on_press(self, event):
        #store initial click coordinates
        self.b_x = event.x
        self.b_y = event.y

    def on_drag(self, event):
        #gather drag coordinates and tag current rect in canvas
        self.drag = True
        self.e_x = event.x
        self.e_y = event.y
        self.canvas.coords('snip_rect', self.b_x, self.b_y, self.e_x, self.e_y)

    def on_release(self, event):
        self.destroy()
        
        #if the user didn't drag, grab an 800x600 image with mouse position as center
        if not self.drag:
            self.b_x -= 400
            self.b_y -= 300
            self.e_x = self.b_x + 800
            self.e_y = self.b_y + 600
        
        #get image based on drag coordinates
        self.master.image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(min(self.b_x, self.e_x), min(self.b_y, self.e_y),
                                                 max(self.b_x, self.e_x), max(self.b_y, self.e_y)))
                                                 
        cv2.imshow('Captured Image Preview', cv2.cvtColor(np.array(self.master.image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        #for storing a snip reference
        self.image = None
        
        #create directory to store snips, if it doesn't exist
        d = path.join(getcwd(), 'snips/')
        if not path.isdir(d):
            mkdir(d)
        
        #snip button
        Button(self, 'Snip', self.snip, 0, 0)
        
        #save button
        self.save_btn = Button(self, 'Save', self.save, 0, 1)
        self.save_btn.configure(state='disabled')
        
    def snip(self):
        self.save_btn.configure(state='normal')   #enable save button
        ScreenSnip(self)                          #start snipper
        
    def save(self):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()                   #destroy image preview
        
        #save image to disk and reset reference
        if self.image:
            self.image.save(f'snips/snip_{strftime("%a_%b_%d_%Y_%I_%M_%S")}.png')
            self.image = None

      
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.title("Snip-N-Save")
    app.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app.mainloop()
```

It may be notable that you could use a hybrid version of your method and my method. You just need to adjust my code so you can adjust the rect. You aren't likely to get a bunch of "edge jumping" with a `Canvas` rect, and in the long run you don't need an entire window. You just need an adjustable rect. This could be that.

If you don't like having a haze over the entire window while you make a selection, do this:

```
class ScreenSnip(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)

        #this ~ you can use any color. I chose this one because it is not likely to be used with any seriousness.
        self.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", '#000001')
        self['background'] = '#000001'

        ...

        #and this
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='#000001')
```

From this example, everything that is the color '#000001' will be transparent clean down to the desktop. Make sure your rect doesn't use that color and voila', you now have something that looks like what you already have, but it should work much better because you are just moving a rect around on a `Canvas`. Keep in mind that you will still have a `tk.Toplevel` covering your entire screen while in "select mode". In other words ... ::click, click, click:: "Why isn't my mouse working?" is in your future if you don't keep this in mind.

Comment: I'm very impressed with that code. Thank you! When I started dumbing it down for what I need it for, I realised it did not support multiple monitors, so added that (code in question update). Since you are much better at this than me, could you have a quick look at my code?

Comment: @JasonFyle - I'm not familiar with the `screeninfo` package. I would say: if it works then you're good to go. Honestly, looking at your code I learned 2 or 3 things that I didn't know. For instance, I didn't know `ImageGrab` had an `all_screens` argument. Style-wise I would get that `App` class out of the `__main__` condition. It's just personal preference, though. I think it looks ugly and cumbersome and it's belongs as an actual part of the main script (unless that's really just an example). Other than that it's perfectly fine.